# Automatically generating and labelling controls in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, variable-definitions, style

Consider the following code

```
Manipulate[n,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"n", Control[{{n, 1, ""}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
    {"eq1", Control[{{eq1, x == 1, ""}, InputField, ImageSize -> Small}]}
    }],
 Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Now, my goal is to generate `n` `InputField`-type controls. That is, whenever I change the value of `n`, I add or remove equation controls with not only the correct labelling (`eq1`, `eq2`, etc), but also the correct variable labelling (within the `Control`, I get `{eqi,x==1,""}}` for each `i` between 1 and `n`). How can I do this efficiently?

A first idea that occured to me was to simply use `Table`, something like

```
Manipulate[n,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"n", Control[{{n, 1, ""}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
    Table[{"eqi", 
      Control[{{eqi, x == 1, ""}, InputField, ImageSize -> Small}]}, {i, n}]
    }],
 Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

where I am, for the moment, ignoring the relabelling bit (`i` should be 1, 2, etc). This, however, doesn't work, since I get

[image]

I tried to use `Flatten`, `Column` and `Sequence@@`, but no success. I want to have something like

[image]

In the end, I have two questions:

1. How do I fix the layout of the `Table` controls?
2. How do I introduce new variables and controls with the correct ordered labelling?

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the labelling, it seems that `StringForm` does the trick. I still don't know how to do the variable labelling though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Column[{n, Column[eq[[;; n]]]}, Dividers -> 1], 
  {{eq, ConstantArray[x == 1, 15]}, ControlType -> None},
  Dynamic@Grid[Join[{{"n", Control@{{n, 1, ""}, 1, 15, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}}}, 
     Table[With[{i = i}, {Style["eq" <> ToString@i, 12], 
       InputField[Dynamic[eq[[i]]], ImageSize -> Small]}], 
       {i, n}]]], 
  Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: My answer is based on your code from the linked question. This answer, however, does not address 1. I do intend to keep the `Grid` encapsulating all controls, including `n`. That's why I used `Sequence@@`. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @samwolfe, pls see the update.