# Table of Variables within Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, symbolic, list-manipulation, variable-definitions, variable

Given a certain number `n`, I want to define `n` controls within `Manipulate` with the correct variable labelling. Visually, I want something like

[image]

where, for example, the output panel is the sum of `ci`'s ($1\leq$`i`$\leq $`n`), that is, 1 if the checkbox is ticked and 0 otherwise.

Using `Dynamic` and `Table` I can get close to my goal with the following code

```
Manipulate[Sum[c1, {i, n}],
 Control[{{n, 1}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
 Dynamic[Table[Control[{{c1, 0}, {1, 0}}], {i, n}] // Column]]
```

[image]

It becomes then a question of defining the variables within the `Table` and `Control` environment. I'm aware of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36886/table-of-variables), but unfortunately using `Symbol` or `ToExpression` within `Control` didn't seem to work.

I'm ultimately asking two questions:

1. How do I correctly introduce and relabel new variables depending on `n`, that is, `c1, c2, ... , cn`? Maybe using `c[i]` instead?
2. If I manage the first, how can I then easily manage such variables for a given output function? For example, if I want to sum them, `Sum[ci,{i,n}]` wouldn't work, so I might need something like `c[i]` or `Symbol["c"<>ToString@i]`.

Any ideas?

PS - This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215630/automatically-generating-and-labelling-controls-in-manipulate). I realised this was trickier than I initially thought and decided to ask a question solely focused on variable definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Sum[cs[[i]], {i, n}],
 {{cs, ConstantArray[0, 10]}, ControlType -> None}, 
 {{n, 1, "n"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Dynamic[Grid[Table[With[{i = i},
      {Symbol["c" <> ToString[i]], Checkbox[Dynamic[cs[[i]]], {0, 1}]}], 
      {i, n}]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Short and elegant. Thank you!